# Element wise numeric comparison in Pandas dataframe column value with list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 3 pandas multiindex column dataframes

dataframe 1(minimum value):

```
  |  A    |   B   |  C   |
  |  Min  |  Min  |  Min |
  |-------|-------|------|
0 | 26.47 | 17.31 | 1.26 |
1 | 27.23 | 14.38 | 1.36 |
2 | 27.23 | 18.88 | 1.28 |
```

dataframe 2 (value used to compare with)

row 0, row 1 and row 2 are the same, I extend the dataframe to three row for comparison with min and max dataframe. Value in each dataframe cell is ndarray

```
  |          A          |           B           |          C         |
  |         Val         |          Val          |         Val        |
  |---------------------|-----------------------|--------------------|
0 | [27.58,28.37,28.73] | [17.31, 18.42, 18.72] | [1.36, 1.28, 1.27] |
1 | [27.58,28.37,28.73] | [17.31, 18.42, 18.72] | [1.36, 1.28, 1.27] |
2 | [27.58,28.37,28.73] | [17.31, 18.42, 18.72] | [1.36, 1.28, 1.27] |
```

dataframe 3(maximum value):

```
  |  A    |   B   |  C   |
  |  Max  |  Max  |  Max |
  |-------|-------|------|
0 | 28.68 | 18.42 | 1.37 |
1 | 29.50 | 17.31 | 1.47 |
2 | 29.87 | 20.45 | 1.39 |
```

Expected result:

```
  |          A          |           B           |          C           |
  |        Result       |          Result       |         Result       |
  |---------------------|-----------------------|----------------------|
0 | [True, True, False] |  [True, True, False]  | [True, True, True]   |
1 | [True, True, True]  | [True, False, False]  | [True, False, False] |
2 | [True, True, True]  | [False, False, False] | [True, True, False]  |
```

I'd like to perform element wise comparison in this way:

```
min <= each element in ndarray <= max
```

i.e

```
for row 0:

26.47 <= [27.58,28.37,28.73] <= 28.68

17.31 <= [17.31, 18.42, 18.72] <= 18.42

1.26 <= [1.36, 1.28, 1.27] <= 1.37
```

and so on

I tried `( datafram2 >= dataframe3 ) & ( datafram2 <= datafram3 )` but not work.

What's the simplest way and fastest way to compute the result?

Example dataframe code:

```
min_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ], [ 'Min' ] ] )
val_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ], [ 'Val' ] ] )
max_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ], [ 'Max' ] ] )

min_df = pd.DataFrame( [ [ 26.47, 17.31, 1.26 ], [ 27.23, 14.38, 1.36 ], [ 27.23, 18.88, 1.28 ] ], columns=min_columns )
val_df = pd.DataFrame( [ [ [ 27.58, 28.37, 28.73 ], [ 17.31, 18.42, 18.72], [1.36, 1.28, 1.27 ] ] ] , columns=val_columns )
max_df = pd.DataFrame( [ [ 28.68, 18.42, 1.37 ], [ 29.50, 17.31, 1.47 ], [ 29.87, 20.45, 1.39 ] ] , columns=max_columns )
```

Comment: Please post the code used to generate the dataframes in this example.

Comment: side note: it's generally bad practice to hold lists/arrays in your dataframe.  This prevents using the full expression of the pandas api, yields poorly performing operations and generally makes things more complex.

Comment: @anon01 Because I'd like to compare each element in list with different combination of max and min, so I have to group the element to be compared with into list and put different min and max to separate dataframes. I am newbie in python and not sure if there is efficient, vertorization way to achieve this, although I know `apply` function performance is not quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn the column values into NumPy arrays. and simply treat it as an array comparing problem (row wise).

You can use `apply`:

```
def bool_check(row):
    col = row.name[0]
    min_val = df1[pd.IndexSlice[col]].to_numpy()
    max_val = df3[pd.IndexSlice[col]].to_numpy()
    x = np.array(row.tolist())
    return list((x >= min_val) & (x <= max_val))
```

---

```
res = df2.apply(bool_check,axis=0).rename(columns={'Val':'Result'})
```

---

**res:**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Result | Result | Result |
| 0 | [True, True, False] | [True, True, False] | [True, True, True] |
| 1 | [True, True, True] | [True, False, False] | [True, False, False] |
| 2 | [True, True, True] | [False, False, False] | [True, True, False] |

### Update

(Complete Solution Based on the data you've provided):

```
def bool_check(row):
    col = row.name[0]
    min_val = min_df[pd.IndexSlice[col]].to_numpy()
    max_val = max_df[pd.IndexSlice[col]].to_numpy()
    x = np.array(row.tolist())
    return list((x >= min_val) & (x <= max_val))

res = val_df.apply(bool_check,axis=0).rename(columns={'Val':'Result'})
```

---

### Time Comparison:

**Method 1 (Nk03's method1):**

> CPU times: user 19.5 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 19.5 ms Wall time: 18.9 ms

**Method 2 (Nk03's method2):**

> CPU times: user 23 ms, sys: 102 µs, total: 23.1 ms Wall time: 21.9 ms

**Method 3 (Using numpy based comparison):**

> CPU times: user 8.76 ms, sys: 26 µs, total: 8.79 ms Wall time: 8.91 ms

**Nk03's Updated and Optimized Solution:**

> CPU times: user 16 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 16 ms Wall time: 15.5 ms

Answer (score 3):

If you've dataframe's like these:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'AMin': {0: 26.47, 1: 27.23, 2: 27.23},
 'BMin': {0: 17.31, 1: 14.38, 2: 18.88},
 'CMin': {0: 1.26, 1: 1.36, 2: 1.28}})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AVal': {0: [27.58, 28.37, 28.73],
  1: [27.58, 28.37, 28.73],
  2: [27.58, 28.37, 28.73]},
 'BVal': {0: [17.31, 18.42, 18.72],
  1: [17.31, 18.42, 18.72],
  2: [17.31, 18.42, 18.72]},
 'CVal': {0: [1.36, 1.28, 1.27], 1: [1.36, 1.28, 1.27], 2: [1.36, 1.28, 1.27]}})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'AMax': {0: 28.68, 1: 29.5, 2: 29.87},
 'BMax': {0: 18.42, 1: 17.31, 2: 20.45},
 'CMax': {0: 1.37, 1: 1.47, 2: 1.39}})
```

Then you can `explode` the 2nd dataframe and compare the values.

```
m = df2.apply(pd.Series.explode).values
df = pd.DataFrame(
    (df1.iloc[np.arange(len(df1)).repeat(3)].values <= m) &
    (m <= df3.iloc[np.arange(len(df3)).repeat(3)].values),
    columns=df2.columns
)

df = df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg(list)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
                     A                      B                     C
0  [True, True, False]    [True, True, False]    [True, True, True]
1   [True, True, True]   [True, False, False]  [True, False, False]
2   [True, True, True]  [False, False, False]   [True, True, False]
```

Comment: Using Apply so many times will make the code extremely slow.

Comment: @Pygirl That's why I added 2 options. 1st one is without `apply`. It's still slow a compared to your answer though  :)

Comment: @Pygirl made several changes to the 1st option. If you don't mind can you compare the performance of the updated option as well?

Comment: Done ^_^.  Are you trying to save line? :P by using `df2.apply(pd.Series.explode)` twice :P